# Answer is Correct but Unpopular

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, quality-improvement

I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010692/google-colab-choosing-specific-python-version/54011659#54011659) a few years back that is technically correct but  not well received. While the answer is *correct*, it's not the answer that people *want* to hear.

I am also confused why the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467489/is-there-a-way-to-use-python-3-5-instead-of-3-6) nearly identical to mine (although with much less traffic) does not receive the disparaging comments mine does.

How do I improve my answer to make it better received?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An answer doesn't have to be incorrect to be "not useful".

There is not much point to answer duplicates when your answer is just repeating what's on the dupe. Having dupe answers on dupe questions fragments information, and means there are now two or more places that we'll need to edit/update if the information becomes out of date in future (for example, colab later adds support for changing runtime).

Sometimes this happens by accident - e.g. you weren't aware of the dupe at the time of answering. When that happens to me I'll usually just delete my answer, leaving the closed question, unanswered, as a "signpost".

Comment: Minor point: Since the answer is accepted, OP is not in a position to delete it. It would require a mod flag, or 3 privileged users to do so.

Comment: This makes sense. It seems I shouldn't have answered the question at all but instead mark as duplicate and link to the existing answer. However, isn't that rather inefficient since it requires all users to follow another link before seeing the unpopular answer? Also, it seems this is just pushing the ire against my answer down the line to the original question answerer.

Comment: @pirateofebay Not all users: visitors to the site who aren't logged in (which is probably even the majority of visitors) will be automatically redirected to the duplicate. The general idea is that the dupe target eventually gets the high google ranking, and dupes add ways for differently worded queries to find their way to that same Q&A.

Comment: Perhaps disparaging is a bit strongly worded :) I'll start the process to delete my answer (assuming I receive the required votes). As a hypothetical follow-up, if this answer was *not* answering a duplicate but still was not well received due to unpopularity, is deletion still the correct course of action?

Comment: @pirateofebay Not really, but it's up to you though. If you feel your answer is useful, then you should leave it up even if it's unpopular. If there's constructive feedback in the comments, try to incorporate that as far as possible, of course.